# What is the purpose of returning $this in PHP

Tags: php

```
function select($select = '*')
    {
        if( is_string($select) ) {
            $select = explode(',', $select) ;
        }

        foreach($select as $s) {
            $s = trim($s) ;

            if($s != '') {
                $this->aSelect[] = $s ;
            }
        }

        return $this ;
    }
```

In PHP, what is meant by `return $this`.

Comment: `return` means what it always means: return a value from a function. `$this` is the current object, usually the object through which the current member function was called.

Comment: by returning $this the function return the current object. then what is the purpose of body of the function. we can write the function somthing (){ retuen $this; }

Comment: I took the liberty to change the title to clarify.

Answer (score 16):

There are many scenarios in which one might want to return `$this` from a function, but the most popular one is 'method chaining'.

For example, in an SQL abstraction layer, you may have an object that represents a query, and then call a series of methods on it to extend it. Consider the following code:

```
$query = $database->select();
$query->from('users');
$query->whereEquals('username', $username);
$query->orderBy('username');
$query->limit(1);
$user = $query->executeSingleRow();
```

If each of `$query`'s methods returns the modified query object, we can instead write this as:

```
$user = $database
            ->select()
            ->from('users')
            ->whereEquals('username', $username)
            ->orderBy('username')
            ->limit(1)
            ->executeSingleRow();
```

The second version is closer to how you'd write an actual SQL query, and it works without introducing the exta `$query` variable.

Answer (score 3):

By returning $this you it makes it easier for the programmer to chain commands. Consider a car object. You could say $car->start()->forward()->left()->forward() on line if you return $this in each function.

There is actually a question about this in stack overflow which could help clarify what method chaining is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining

Answer (score 0):

Chian type programming...
 return $this will return a same object all the time. that make you be ready to call upon it a next function, next function again return same instance such that to call upon it a third function and so on.

see example first

```
class MY_CLASS(){
    string attrib; 
    func SetMethod(string value){this.attrib=value;}
}
```

to call Method1 on un-known object,  we can write as following.

```
(new MY_CLASS()).Method1
```

expend above class

```
 class MY_CLASS(){
        string attrib; 
       func SetMethod(string value){this.attrib=value;}
       func int GetMethod(){return this.Attrib);}
    }
```

Now to call it for GetMethod we can't  do with un-known object as following
new MY_CLASS().SetMethod(30);
a = new My_CLASS().GetMethod();

Yah in other languages like C# we can do as following

```
a=(new MY_CLASS().SetMethod(30)).GetMethod();
```

to achieve same facilities in php you need to write 'return $this' in function where you think to be use for consegative calls

Hope answer is clear.